# Statistics Independent Probability

Tags: probability

Sheriff Joe Stewart thinks the probability that any law enforcement grant is funded .25. He believes that the decision to fund one grant is independent of the decision to find another grant. He submits 3 grants. 
1) What is the probability that he gets none funded?
2) What is the probability that he gets exactly 1 funded?
3) What is the probability that he gets exactly 2 funded?
4) What is the probability that he 2 or more funded?

I tried answering the questions but am not sure if it's right...
1) (1 - .25) x (1 - .25) x (1 - .25)
2) (1 - .25) x (1 - .25) x .25
3) (1 - .25) x .25 x .25
4) (.25^3) + ((1 - .25) x .25 x .25)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

1) $(.75)^3$

2) ${3 \choose 1}(.25)^1 (.75)^2$

3) ${3 \choose 2} (.25)^2 (.75)^1$

4) ${3 \choose 2} (.25)^2 (.75)^1 + (.25)^3$